# Parallelize get_serving_url in GAE Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, tasklet

The [Traces](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/) graph showed `/images.GetUrlBase` calls for my search function. I tried to make it call `get_serving_url ()` in parallel but still the [Traces](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/) graph shows the calls as sequential.
How do I make it parallel ?

[image]

**My Attempt**

```
class Gets 
    @staticmethod 
    @ndb.tasklet 
    def get_img_url_parallel ( image_key ): 
        url     = yield images.get_serving_url_async (image_key) 
        raise ndb.Return ( url ) 


@toplevel 
def search (..): 
    :: 
    for record in record_list: 
        :: 
        for photo in record.photo_list: 
            if (photo != ""): 
                yielded_photo   = yield Gets.get_img_url_parallel ( photo ) 
                photo_list.append ( yielded_photo  ) 
::
```

I am new to yield, tasklet.

Comment: I wonder why you have two yields?

Comment: @TimHoffman
Since decorator `@ndb.tasklet` causes sub `get_img_url_parallel` to return a `Future`, I thought I either need to call `get_result()` or `yield` to get the actual value. What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: You certainly don't call yield twice - though it's probably not the issue.  Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

Comment: @TimHoffman I went through it and was not able to understand how to use it in my scenario mentioned above. I would again try and get back.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. The docs are pretty clear, in addition this article covers using urlfetch asynchronously https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests

Comment: @TimHoffman Thanks for the tip. I was able to figure it out ( finally ). The documentation was confusing to me since it tells about NDB but I later understood it after repeated iterations. I would post the solution later with proper explanation.

Comment: I wonder why is this related to ndb? We dont do any datastore related stuff